# BrowserSync не видит стили (локально всё отображается)

Tags: css, gulp, browsersync, gulp-sass, пути

Настроила BrowserSync, стили на нём подгружаются лишь при нахождении html-файла в папке над css. При размещении в соседнюю папку - отключаются (локально в браузере видны в любом расположении).

То есть, при построении проекта с html в корневой папке и путём в подключении стилей
`"styles/styles.css"` всё работает и локально в браузере, и при запуске Sync-сервера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При размещении проекта в соседней папке с путём `"../styles/styles.css"` стили видны только локально в браузере, сервер Sync-а их не отображает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С этим вариантом директории отображаются, при `"build/pages"` - нет.

```
'use strict';
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    pug = require('gulp-pug'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    notify = require("gulp-notify"),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

gulp.task('serve', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./build"    //при замене на "./build/pages" стили не видны
        }
    });
    browserSync.watch('build', browserSync.reload)
});
sass.compiler = require('node-sass');

gulp.task('pug', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/pug/pages/*.pug')
        .pipe(pug({
            pretty:true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));    //тут тоже должно собираться в "build/pages"
});
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/static/scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            cascade: false
        }))
        .on("error", notify.onError({
            message: "Error: <%= error.message %>",
            title: "Error styles file"
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/styles'))
});
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('src/static/scss/*.scss', gulp.parallel('sass')); 
    gulp.watch('src/pug/pages/*.pug', gulp.parallel('pug')); 
});
gulp.task('default', gulp.series(
    gulp.parallel('pug', 'sass'),
    gulp.parallel('watch', 'serve')
));
```

В чём может быть проблема? Нагуглить не удалось, в вопросах подобной проблемы с путями не нашла. Делала по видеосборке с ютуба, там просто в корневую папку положили.

Comment: у вас же препроцессор sass используется, css автоматически генерируется и не отслеживается browser-sync. удалите папку build и запустите задачу по умолчанию и посмотрите, где css окажется. если не там, где хотите, исправьте задачу sass.

Comment: @АлексейОбухов да, используется scss. Удалила, всё собирается по папкам как задумано, стили в Sync по-прежнему видны лишь при перемещении html в корневую папку над css (при запуске локально стили подключаются при любом расположении html-файла).

Comment: видны из html? так исправьте href в link. Sync по вашему таску watch смотрит файлы pug и sass. только эти файлы вы имеете право менять. остальные не править и не перемещать. Кстати, запустите в соседней папке (где не создаются стили) таск sass и посмотрите консольный вывод, вполне возможно была ошибка.